# Visual Studio 2010 file could not be found in your workspace issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, workspace

I'm getting this message when connected to a TFS repository and trying to edit a local `.sql` file **that's not yet in the repository**.

> The item C:\bla\blabla\blablabla\USP_BLA.sql could not be found in
>   your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it. No items
>   were checked out

If I disconnect from the TFS repository everything is fine. If I re-connect to the TFS repository I start getting the message, even just trying to type/save the file.

**The file is actually there in my local folder and I have the corresponding permissions, for those who are thinking otherwise.** It is just a text file that I should be able to edit irrespective of whether I'm connected to the repository or not.

I got Windows SP1 installed on my Windows 7 this morning; don't know if that could be the cause of the issue. We are using the.NET Framework 4.

Any idea of what the issue is or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with one of the "facts" in my question, "file that's not yet in the repository".

A file with the same file name I had locally was already there in the TFS repository, it had been checked-in a month ago by someone else.

Only when I tried to check-in the new local copy I became aware of that; the file was not supposed to be there.

Anyway, after checking-out the file from TFS everything went back to normal; I'm able to edit/save the file without issues, even if connected to TFS.

Comment: You just saved my day.  A strange feeling knowing other people have had the same insane issues.

Comment: I got this error after adding a new form to my project. After reading this I tried again and this time gave the new form another name and now it worked. So I guess the form was created once before with this name and removed and TFS still has some link to this first form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the latest version of your source code It should resolve the issue..Or Get Specific Version and allow to overwrite existing files.If still does not resolve make sure the file is present on local directory.

Do not forget to rebuild after getting latest code